# DataContractJsonSerializer fails on generic / polymorphic objects

Tags: c#, generics, datacontractserializer

Trying to abstract my program, I use f-bounded polymorphism to define my values. I use `DataContractJsonSerializer` (no choice for that). The only problem is that apparently for generics, it throws an `XmlException` saying that the type name is badly formatted (5th line from the end below).

```
public abstract class Value<T> where T : Value<T> {
}
public class StringValue : Value<StringValue> {
    [DataMember]
    public string S { get; set; }
}

[DataContract, KnownType("GetSubclasses")]
public abstract class Tree<TValue> where TValue : Value<TValue> {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetSubclasses() {
        return from t in typeof(Tree<>).Assembly.GetTypes()
               where typeof(Tree<>).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select t;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    protected Tree() {}
}

[DataContract]
public class ConcTree<TValue> : Tree<TValue> where TValue : Value<TValue> { 
    [DataMember]
    public TValue Value;

    public ConcTree(string n, TValue reg) {
        Name = n;
        Value = reg;
    }
}

var result = new ConcTree<StringValue>("test", new StringValue() { S = "s_value" });
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (Tree<StringValue>));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, result); // Here XmlException
    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It throws an `XmlException` or a `System.InvalidOperationException`, depending on some parameters.

> The '{' character, hexadecimal value 0x7B, cannot be included in a name."}    System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}

When debug the variables I find this:

```
    localName       "TreeOf{0}{#}"        string
```

which is tested in a function named IsValidNCName. 
How can I overcome these exceptions? Before using generics I never had them, but I don't want to go back.

**--edit--**

I tried to use `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (ConcTree<StringValue>));` so that it takes the correct type, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 36h of searching, I finally found the correct way. Instead of looking in the registered types in the assembly, I add a static initializer to all subclasses of `Tree` which register their type.

**Furthermore** I have to add the generic parameter `TValue` to the list of known types (see #1) if I have an advanced class hierarchy, especially for deserialization. See the last part.

```
[DataContract, KnownType("GetKnownSubclassesOfRegion")]
public abstract class Value<T> where T : Value<T> {
    //Register sub-types statically.
    protected static readonly List<Type> ValueTypes= new List<Type>();
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownSubclassesOfRegion() {
       return RegionTypes;
   }
}
[DataContract]
public class StringValue : Value<StringValue> {
    [DataMember]
    public string S { get; set; }
    static StringValue() {
        ValueTypes.Add(typeof(StringValue ));
    }
}
```

And the same for the tree :

```
[DataContract, KnownType("GetSubclasses")]
public abstract class Tree<TValue> where TValue : Value<TValue> {
    //Register sub-types statically with their generic parameter which is instantiated.
    protected static readonly List<Type> RegisteredTypes = new List<Type>();
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetSubclasses() {      //This is new
        return RegisteredTypes;
    }
    static TreeElement() { // #1
        RegisteredTypes.Add(typeof(TValue));
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    protected Tree() {}
}

[DataContract]
public class ConcTree<TValue> : Tree<TValue> where TValue : Value<TValue> { 
    [DataMember]
    public TValue Value;

    public ConcTree(string n, TValue reg) {
        Name = n;
        Value = reg;
    }

    static ConcTree() {  //This is new
        ValueTypes.Add(typeof(ConcTree<TValue>)); 
    }
}

var result = new ConcTree<StringValue>("test", new StringValue() { S = "s_value" });
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (Tree<StringValue>));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, result); // No exception anymore.
    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And now it works perfectly !